# Easiest way from 2x10 (0.05" pitch) header to 0.1"

Tags: debugging, prototyping, header, pin-headers

As per title, I have a debug header with a 2x10 0.05" setup on a board I'm working with. This was chosen because of the space constraints. I'm looking for the cleanest way to go from this header to a standard 0.1" pitch header that I can connect my logic analyzer and other debugging equipment to.

For the 2x5 I'm using this Adafruit breakout board[1] that works really well, but couldn't find something similar for 2x10.

[1] https://www.adafruit.com/product/2743

Comment: Make your own ?

Comment: What would I need? I'm not very friendly with the soldering iron, I'm a code guy :)

Comment: You need to make a layout using some tool like KiCad, export the gerbers, send them to a cheap fab like elecrow, seeedstudio, whatever, order the header on some electronic component site like mouser, digikey, farnell, whatever, buy a soldering iron and solder wire, and assemble this. All in all, it's not that hard, but the soldering part is just a detail. In any case, your question is either a shopping question, or way too broad if you want to do it yourself and need each step to be detailed. Both reasons make your question off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of 0.05" pitch 20-pin adapters available on e.g. Digikey.  Just search for prototyping/adapter boards and select your pitch.  Something like this?[image: 20-pin breakout adapter]